# Rails Order Find By Boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple find in rails 3 that gathers users accounts.

```
 Account.where(:user_id => @user)
```

The Account model has a 'default' boolean field.  As a user adds many accounts I would like the default account to always be first in the loop.  Order doesn't seem to work with a boolean field.

```
  Account.where(:user_id => @user, :order => "default DESC")
```

Is there a way to order the query to handle this or should I just split the queries and find the default account in a separate find?

Comment: @account.ratings.all.sort_by { |a| a.default ? 0 : 1 } seems to work in the console.  However, Im using jQuery dataTable and it doesn't affect the sort order in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Account.where(:user_id => @user).order("default DESC")` - putting `:order` in your `where()` clause isn't going to sort the result set.

A cleaner solution might be to add a scope, though.

```
scope :default_first, order(arel_table[:default].desc)
```

Then you could just call (assuming your relations are set up properly):

```
@user.accounts.default_first.all
```